# Asynchronous WebService in OSB

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous, osb

How to make WEB-Service Asynchronous in Oracle Service Bus. 
please let guide to develop it!!

```
http://www.html2xml.nl/Services/Calculator/Version1/Calculator.asmx?wsdl
```

this is web service of Calculator, I have to call asynchronous web service in osb.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand the question. You want to create an asynchronous OSB Proxy service? Or you want to call the Calculator Web service asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but every call to a proxy service is synchronous. If you want it to be asynchronous, you should put your message from the first service on an JMS queue and let them be read by another service.

Answer (score 0):

Read about OSB [thread model](https://blogs.oracle.com/reynolds/entry/following_the_thread_in_osb). If you call a webservice via Routing, then exactly this service call asynchronously: your thread do not blocked and return to the thread pool after request sending. A multiplexor (muxer) is used to wait for the response. Whan the service accepted and return response, the muxer hands off the response to a new thread that is used to execute the response pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I also think putting the intial call into a JMS queue is a good method to make the WS async and to enable transaction security once something goes wrong in OSB or target system.

[ASYNC WS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4PAs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Publish the request into a JMS Queue using a business service with jms protocol.
Now construct a jms proxy over the same queue. In the message flow transform the message and call to the web service that you want to asynchronize. 
In the end, publish the response into another queue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enable/enforce WS-Addressing in your WSDL.
Save the replyTo and operation values in the WS-Addressing headers.
Perform your internal processing.  If this will require calling another asynchronous service, then use a JMS queue or DB table for temporary storage of the response, and poll that queue/table for the response.
When you receive the response, and/or complete your internal processing, invoke the client using a dynamic route node.
You will need to use the replyTo and operation from earlier to construct the XML for the dynamic route.
That's it!